# Converted Jar to Exe, opens up cmd prompt

Tags: java, cmd, exe

I converted a jar to exe using excelsior, and it worked out perfectly. Only problem is when I open it, it also opens up a cmd prompt. Usually that would be no problem, but I'm trying to multibox a game with a program that only runs .exe's, and it considers the cmd prompt the game, but it opens the game up through the program.

So when I try to control the game it's sending it to the cmd prompt and not the actual game.

Any help?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the tool, but if there's an option to specify the java executable try "javaw" rather than "java"

Comment: I've had more success using Launch4j http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Open your project in the Excelsior JET Control Panel, go to the Appearance page and select "Hide console window".